# Group by one field and display multiple fields (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have these three tables :

Booking :

```
+----+---------+--------+---------------+-------------+
| id | idRoom  | idUser | startDateTime | endDateTime |
+----+---------+--------+---------------+-------------+
|  4 |       3 |      1 | 07/06/2020    | 07/07/2020  |
|  5 |      3  |     2  | 07/06/2021    | 07/06/2021  |
+----+---------+--------+---------------+-------------+
```

Room :

```
+----+--------------+
| id | description  |
+----+--------------+
|  3 | Room 1       |
+----+--------------+
```

User :

```
+----+----------+
| id | userName |
+----+----------+
|  1 | User 1   |
|  2 | User 2   |
+----+----------+
```

And want to select all the bookings (listed in table one) while displaying the User and the Room fields infos and group by the Room object.
I am using the `JOIN` clause along with the `GROUP BY` clause as follows :

```
select distinct r, b, u 
from Booking b 
join Room r on b.idRoom=r.id 
join User u on b.idUser=u.id 
where r.id=3
group by r, b, u 
order by r
```

But it is not rendering the desired result.
Anyone suggests a working SQL query ?

EDIT (Desired Result ) :

```
+-------+--------+-----------+
| Rooms  | Users  | Bookings  |
+-------+--------+-----------+
|     3 |      1 |         4 |
|       |      2 |         5 |
+-------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: What is your desired result? What do you expect to get back from MySQL?

Comment: Syntactically that's a mess. You cannot select table names and where r.id=:roomid has a completely wrong =:

Comment: My expected result is to get two Json objects grouped by the Room object (here i have one room with id 3 booked twice by User 1 and User 2 at different times, so i want to get a list of the Users and Bookings under one Room Object.

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry it is because i copied the query from a Java Code ! i edited the query now !

Comment: `r`, `b`, and `u` are not defined.  You need to provide sample data and desired results.  Your description of `group by` doesn't make sense.

Comment: `Booking b`, `User u`, `Room r`, i don't understand what do you mean by sample data : i added three tables with sample data. DESIRED RESULT IS TO GROUP BY THE ROOM OBJECT so that room object is factorized while displaying the two associated bookings and user infos.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please see EDIT for detailed desired results !

Comment: This is a strange result you are expecting. A query result is a table. So you should be able to show the expected result just like you show your sample tables, with columns and rows. How would that result table have to look like?

Comment: @kettner pls see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wants to group by your query output by room, you can start your query from the room table. But not sure how you can get the Json formatted output. You can achieve the following output and rest part you should manage in the frontend.

Possible output-

```
Rooms  Users  Bookings
3      1      4
3      2      5
```

Query for the above output -

```
SELECT R.id AS Rooms,
B.idUser AS Users,
B.ID AS Bookings
FROM Room R
INNER JOIN Booking B ON R.Id = B.idRoom
```

For more details of a User, you can join the User table Now.

Comment: Thanks for your try BUT i need to display the room id only once ! and then below that the two bookings infos (including the users infos) this query rather display the room  info twice so it is not quiet what i want to achieve

Comment: thats not database part and you can not achieve that output using query, you need to achive that in your fronend.

Comment: You are most welcome. Nice to see that it helped :)